# Create new calculation field - campaign type in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-ads-api, looker-studio

I trying to create calculation field in Google Data Studio. I want to recognize in detail my campaign type. Default It's "Display Only", "Search Only"  or "Shopping". I'm interested to add other options, like: GMAIL or Youtube based on function REGEXP_MATCH and name of my campaigns. This is the code, This is the code which I wrote:

```
CASE
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*[REM].*") THEN "Display"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*[REM].*") THEN "Display - remarketing"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Search Only") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*[GSN].*") THEN "Search"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Search Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*[GSN].*") THEN "Search"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Shopping") THEN "Reklama produktowa"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*[YT].*") THEN "Display - Youtube"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*[GMAIL].*") THEN "Display - Gmail"
END
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex master and you haven't described the error you're getting but I'm guessing an error might be caused by the square brackets?

```
CASE
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*REM.*") THEN "Display"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*REM.*") THEN "Display - remarketing"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Search Only") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*GSN.*") THEN "Search"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Search Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*GSN.*") THEN "Search"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Shopping") THEN "Reklama produktowa"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*YT.*") THEN "Display - Youtube"
WHEN Campaign type IN ("Display Only") AND REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "(?i).*GMAIL.*") THEN "Display - Gmail"
END
```